# Sitecore MVC Bundling Optimization

Tags: bundling

I have created bundling in my project as follows :
Have created a config under App_Start/BundleConfig.cs

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }        
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {            
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include("~/Assets/Project/scripts/main.js"));           
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include("~/Assets/Project/styles/main.css"));
    }        
}
```

and added the same in Pipeline

```
<initialize>
    <processor type="MyProject.Foundation.Assets.App_Start.BundleConfig, MyProject.Foundation.Assets" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
  </initialize>
```

So the bundling is working fine as expected.

But now I need to optimize them using a query parameter in the URL, example if I browse example.local?debug=true, I need to enable optimizations as false

So now I have added another config

```
public class BundleOptimizations : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {            
        EnableOptimizations();
    }       

    public void EnableOptimizations()
    {
        var debugMode = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["debug"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(debugMode) && string.Equals(debugMode, "true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
        }
        else
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }

    }
}
```

and this config I have added in HttpRequestBegin pipeline

```
<httpRequestBegin>
    <processor type="MyProject.Foundation.Assets.App_Start.BundleOptimizations, MyProject.Foundation.Assets" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
  </httpRequestBegin>
```

But I am not able to get these bundles optimized using the query parameter. Please can someone help me with the same

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for providing a single line answer.

Here is what i did to get the optimization done :

In my question, I had mentioned about the BundeOptimizations which I had created inheriting HttpRequesProcessor and placing the same in the httpRequestBegin. So while I was investigaing on the same I came across the show config which has the following registered in the preprocess request :

```
<processor type="Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.PreProcessRequest.HandleBundleRequest, Sitecore.FXM" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.FXM.Bundle.config">
```

And when i decompiled the code, I could see that they were registering the bundles in this.

Then I tried to implement my optimization code inside the preprocess request as follows

```
public class BundleOptimizations : PreprocessRequestProcessor
{    
        public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
        {            
            EnableOptimizations();
        }       

        public static void EnableOptimizations()
        {
          var debugMode = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["debug"];
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(debugMode) && string.Equals(debugMode, "true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
          {
              BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
          }
          else
          {
              BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
          }

        }
}
```

and then updated the same in preprocessrequest config

```
<preprocessRequest>
    <processor type="Project.Foundation.Assets.App_Start.BundleOptimizations, Project.Foundation.Assets" />
</preprocessRequest>
```

Then i tried to add the URL with ?debug =true in it and it worked.

Thanks